# Spring LDAP basic usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

I'm trying to figure out how Spring LDAP (*not* the Spring security thing) works by setting up the most basic working program, but it seems that the actual authentication breaks.

This is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:125)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:237)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:588)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:546)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:421)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:441)
```

The code that's executed in the method that's throwing the exception is:

```
return getContext(authenticationSource.getPrincipal(),
                  authenticationSource.getCredentials());
```

So it seems like I need to set up an authentication source in the application context? I'm really lost.

Here's my code:

```
package se.test.connector.ldap;

import java.util.List;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.ldap.filter.EqualsFilter;

public class LdapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
        ctxSrc.setUrl("ldap://<ldapUrl>:389");
        ctxSrc.setBase("DC=bar,DC=test,DC=foo");
        ctxSrc.setUserDn("<username>@bar.test.foo");
        ctxSrc.setPassword("<password>");

        LdapTemplate tmpl = new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);

        PersonDao dao = new PersonDao(tmpl);
        dao.getAllPersonNames();
    }

    public static class PersonDao {

        private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

        public PersonDao(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
            this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
        }

        public void setLdapTemplate(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
            this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
        }

        public List getAllPersonNames() {
            EqualsFilter filter = new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person");
            return ldapTemplate.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH,
                    filter.encode(),
                    new AttributesMapper() {

                        public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
                            return attrs.get("cn").get();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks proper, on the surface. One thing, your userDn is not really a proper distinguished name. It ought to be on the format "`CN=<...>, DC=bar, DC=test, DC=foo`". Since you give no details on which LDAP server you are using or how your directory structure looks (OU structure etc) it's hard to be more precise.

Comment: Indded, I never tried to separately set the user "base" and the uid.
Try to not set base and to set UserDN with the fully qualified DN.

Answer (score 24):

I had very a similar Problem - also with `NullPointerException`.

What solved my Problem was a call of [afterPropertiesSet()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.2.0/api/spring-ldap/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/AbstractContextSource.html#afterPropertiesSet%28%29):

```
// ...

LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
ctxSrc.setUrl("ldap://<ldapUrl>:389");
ctxSrc.setBase("DC=bar,DC=test,DC=foo");
ctxSrc.setUserDn("<username>@bar.test.foo");
ctxSrc.setPassword("<password>");

ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet(); /* ! */

LdapTemplate tmpl = new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);

// ...
```

Comment: afterPropertiesSet() call solved my problem, while I had the same nullpointer exception

Comment: this is the real answer, if you got a NPE caused by authenticationSource == null